# HtmlWebpackPlugin ignores filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, asp.net-core, webpack

I'm trying out code/bundle splitting with webpack, however I ran in to an issue. HTMLWebpackPlugin is as far as I know supposed to dynamically insert script tags into an HTML file. This HTML file is by default index.html and it seems to work when I use the default. Because I use .NET with a _Layout.cshtml and Index.cshtml, it would like it to use the Index.cshtml.

HTMLWebpackPlugin seems to completely ignore what is in "filename", and generates an index.html:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: '../../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml',
        filename: 'test-index.html' // Generates index.html, not test-index.html...
        //filename: '../Views/Home/Index.cshtml' // Not working either. Generates index.html
    })
```

webpack.common.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './ClientApp/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './ClientApp/vendor.ts',
        'app': './ClientApp/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: { configFileName: helpers.root('ClientApp', 'tsconfig.json') }
                    } , 'angular2-template-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['raw-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('ClientApp', 'app'),
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },

    optimization:
    {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name(module) {
                        // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                        // or node_modules/packageName
                        const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

                        // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                        return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    },

    plugins: [    
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(@angular|fesm5)/,
            helpers.root('ClientApp'),
            {}
        ),

        new webpack.BannerPlugin('© COPYRIGHT LIGHTHOUSE INTELLIGENCE ' + new Date().getFullYear()),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: '../../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml',
            filename: 'test-index.html' // Generates index.html, not test-index.html...
            //filename: '../Views/Home/Index.cshtml' // Not working either
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: helpers.root('/wwwroot/dist'),
        publicPath: '/wwwroot/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js', //.[hash]
        chunkFilename: '[id].js' //.chunk
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you cant do that. Razor cshtml file need to have everything include in the view before you build and run your project so that it can build and transform cshtml to html.

htmlwebpackplugin only work with html so the only option you can choose is serve the html file in your .net core project

Answer (score -1):

Location of the output file is determined by the **output** attribute of webpack.config.js (path: helpers.root('/wwwroot/dist')). So you have to specify only the file name for the **filename** attribute.